# How to specify a border for a TreeView inside of a MetroWindow?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, mahapps.metro

I just started using the `MetroWindow` found within the MahApps.Metro package and I noticed that the `TreeView` in my XAML no longer has a border. I've tried the following but it didn't seem to have any affect:

```
<TreeView x:Name="AssetsTreeView" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Assets}"
    Height="250"
    BorderThickness="2"
    BorderBrush="Black">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

In my `App.xaml` I have the following 4 style pages referenced:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
```

I'm guessing the culprit is in one of the styles but I figured I could overwrite it via `BorderBrush` and `BorderThickness` on the `TreeView` element itself (which doesn't seem to be the case). Is there something I'm missing to do this or does this have to be a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you can get access to the `ControlTemplate` then it sounds like you won't be able to set the normal `Border` properties on that `TreeView`. You might just have to settle for creating your own (from the default `TreeView ControlTemplate` found in the [TreeView Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752048%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN):

```
<Border Name="Border" CornerRadius="1" BorderThickness="1">
    <Border.BorderBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" />
    </Border.BorderBrush>
    <Border.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
    </Border.Background>
    <TreeView ... />
</Border>
```

At least this way, you'll be able to customise to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no Border with a TemplateBinding on BorderThickness in the Treeview's template defined by the style in, I think Controls.xaml, setting it in the declaration of your treeview will indeed have no effect.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TreeView}" TargetType="TreeView">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeView">
        <Border Name="Border"
BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" <- these may be lacking in the 
BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">        <- template defined in the 
                                                       overriding style.
  [...]
```